# how to insert values from uitextfield n also an image in sqlite?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uiimage

In my database I have table AnimalDetails containing animalNumber(primary key),name,breed dateofbirth and an image fields. I want to add data to this table.
I have created 3 textfield for name,breed n dateofbirth and uiimageview which picks image from imagepicker,animalNumber is a random generated number.
Now I want to add this data to my tabel.

Please help me !

Comment: insert into tablename values(id,name) ; or insert into tablename("id","name") values(id,name);

Comment: Beware that if you do not copy the database file to the document directory you will not be able to write to the file. Since all files in the MainBundle are read only.

Comment: @rckoenes: Spot on! +1 for Good observation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you know how to **open** database.

Once you open the database you need to call a method where in you insert the data in database as follows:

```
- (BOOL) insertContactDetails
{
    char *st, *errorMsg;

    st = sqlite3_mprintf("INSERT INTO contactDetails (`Id`,`Name`) VALUES"
                         " (%d,'%s')",                          
                         [textId.text intValue],[txtName UTF8String]);

    NSLog(@"QUERY: %@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:st]);
    int ret = sqlite3_exec(yourDB, st, NULL, NULL, &errorMsg); //yourDB is declared as "sqlite3 *yourDB;"

    if (ret != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_free(errorMsg);
        sqlite3_free(st);
        return NO;
    }
    sqlite3_free(st);
    return YES;
}
```

Once you execute this query you need to close the database.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQLite directly on iOS, I would use FMDB: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Then use `executeUpdate:` or `executeUpdateWithFormat:` using the proper `INSERT` syntax to insert into your contactDetails table.